# jQuery .val() not working

Tags: jquery

I feel stupid but I have an input

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="b4-panel-1" name="request[3][vehicles][1][regNumber]" value="eqweq" style="">
```

And

```
$('#b4-panel-1').val()
```

returns empty string "" instead of "eqweq"

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you written your script in document.load?

Comment: Put you code inside ready function `$(function(){ //your code here })`

Comment: Can you  setup a jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry it was my bad, due to something else. The topic can be closed.

Comment: Your code is working perfectly.